# Relation between an Abelian subgroup of a group and center of the group.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Original Question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $N \trianglelefteq G$. $N$ is abelian. If $\gcd(|G/N|,|\text{Aut}(G)|)=1$, then prove that $N \subseteq Z(G)$.

All I could find is that Inner Automorphisms of $N$ is trivial and the automorphism group is of the form $|N|k, k\in \mathbb{N}.$ I am feeling kind of lost and just wanted a push in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much, was stuck at question for a day and a half.

Comment: Please don't use math mode for quotes like that. Press the edit button to see how one ought to do it (it's a lot easier than using backslashes for each space, and it looks much better).

Comment: okay will do from next time